# install R package from private repo owned by github organisation

Tags: r, github, r-package

I am unsure how to install an R package which I have hosted on a private repo owned by an organisation. Previously the repo would have been owned by myself and as an individual user I could use a Personal Access Token and the 'auth_token' argument of devtools::install_github. As far as I am aware this isn't possible for an organisation (github teams). Are there any other solutions that could work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `install_git` instead.

To make sure you have the credentials set-up properly, try a repository cloning attempt with git alone in the shell:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/repository.git
```

Then in R try installing the package with:

```
R> devtools::install_git('ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/repository.git')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this work for users other than me. Ideally I would like even those without access to the github organisation to be able to install the package (if they have a given password/token etc). Could see how your suggestion would work just for me

Comment: I don't know. Sorry I only use public repositories on github.