# Unable to install github package with devtools::install_github()

Tags: r, github, devtools

When I try to install a package from github I am gettin the following error:

```
devtools::install_github("<DeveloperName>/<PackageName>")
Error: HTTP error 404.

 Not Found

  Rate limit remaining: 24/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2019-01-07 21:36:52 UTC
```

This doesn't make sense to me as the "/" are correctly entered and till take me to the repo when entered into my browser when entered after github.com. (Apologies that the repo is private to my company or I would share the actual developer and repo names.)

My traceback reads:

```
8.stop(github_error(res))
7.github_commit(username = remote$username, repo = remote$repo, host = remote$host, ref = remote$ref, pat = remote$auth_token %||% github_pat(), use_curl = use_curl)
6.remote_sha.github_remote(remote, local_sha)
5.remote_sha(remote, local_sha)
4.FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3.vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = character(1))
2.install_remotes(remotes, auth_token = auth_token, host = host, dependencies = dependencies, upgrade = upgrade, force = force, quiet = quiet, build = build, build_opts = build_opts, repos = repos, type = type, ...)
1.devtools::install_github("<DeveloperName>/<PackageName>")
```

I cannot find documentation to explain my final traceback error:  "stop(github_error(res))". I have updated to latest version of devtools, but the problem persists.

Comment: Is problem specific to this repo, or have you tried other repos? If that's a private repo, have you set your [personal access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171142/how-to-install-r-package-from-private-repo-using-devtools-install-github)? Are you sure your account has permissions to the repo?

Comment: @MrFlick I have set my personal access token and I have confirmed that I have permissions to the repo. I had no problem installing dev version of gganimate using install_github() just now.

Comment: Then if it's specific to this repo, it's going to be hard to help you without specifics. Have you tried this method maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064119/install-r-package-from-private-repo-owned-by-github-organisation

Comment: can you clone the repo?

Comment: @DS_UNI Yes I can .

Comment: until you find the cause of the problem, you can as workaround  clone the repo and then use ``devtools::load_all()``